# Difference between Expression.Call overloads?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I was attempting to dynamically create a Where predicate for a LINQ2SQL query:

```
...Where(SqlMethods.Like(r.Name, "%A%") ||
         SqlMethods.Like(r.Name, "%B%") ||
         SqlMethods.Like(r.Name, "%C%") || ...)
```

A, B, C, etc. come from some array. So I tried the following:

```
var roleExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Role), r);
var nameExpression = Expression.Property(roleExpression, "Name");
var termExpression = Expression.Constant("%" + term[i] + "%");
var likeExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(SqlMethods), "Like",
    new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }, nameExpression, termExpression);
```

However, the last line fails with the message *No method 'Like' on type 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods' is compatible with the supplied arguments*.

So I tried the following line:

```
var likeExpression = Expression.Call(null,
    typeof(SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }),
    nameExpression, searchTermExpression)
```

This works. However, I don't understand what the difference is between these two lines. In my opinion they should deliver the same result.

Could anyone explain this?

Kind regards,
Ronald Wildenberg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the `Type[]` argument is for *generic type parameters* - i.e. you were trying to call:

```
SqlMethods.Like<string,string>(...); // note the <string,string>
```

Try passing an empty `Type[]`.

---

Edit re the confusion (comments); my point is: you shouldn't be specifying **anything** for the `Type[]` argument. Either an empty array or null would do; for example:

```
var likeExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(SqlMethods), "Like", null, nameExpression, termExpression);
```

Comment: There is no SqlMethods.Like method that accepts generic type arguments, so this can not be the difference between both calls.

Comment: You missed the point of my reply... it is preciseley ***because*** of this that it fails... (generic type args)

Comment: Ah, I see. As always it's a matter of reading the documentation carefully. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I do not have enough reputation to vote up your answer... I'll come back as soon as I have.

Comment: No problem - feel free to mark as answered if you like, though... (the tick)

Comment: I've ever seen this: new Type[0].

Comment: @LeiYang well, `new Foo[n]` is a "new array, element-type `Foo`, length `n`" - so a `new Type[0]` is simply a new empty `Type`-array, i.e. a `Type[]` with no contents. Actually, `Type.EmptyTypes` is the same thing without the extra allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class from Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari to build your where predicate

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the next:

```
Expression.Call(Nothing, GetType(System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods).GetMethod("Like", New Type() {GetType(String), GetType(String)}), New Expression() {left, right})
```